# How to refresh ListView when being displayed in ViewPager?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have 2 activities in a ViewPager. Activity A adds items to a database, and Activity B displays those added items in a ListView. I have a method called `GetFavs()` which connects to the database and pulls the data and displays the items.
How can I call `GetFavs()` method each time activity B is displayed in ViewPager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create static adapter in B and each time when you add new items in A you can do smth like this

```
if (B.adapter != null){
    ...//Add items to your adapter
    B.adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

With this code you can not load full data each time you see B.
Also you can pass the whole B context and create method to add new item in it.

```
B parent;
parent.addItemToList(Item item);
```